# How to install com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: jdbc, drivers

How do I install com.mysql.jdbc.Driver for **Fedora17 O.S** using **jdk version 1.7**
I always get an error of could not find Driver with class name:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver in all my jdbc codes.

Comment: @Pshemo sir please help me out with this if possible

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java connectivity with MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/java-connectivity-with-mysql)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you already have MySQL installed,

1. Install the connector driver. : `yum install libmysql-java`
2. Then make sure that the classpath is set.

   `export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar`

   If you want to set this for all users, you should modify the `/etc/environment` instead

If you are using Eclipse, you can also do this by going through the following steps:

- Select `Project Properties > Java Build Path`
- Select Libries tab
- Click Add External Jars
- Choose the jar file, in this case `mysql-connector-java.jar`

Comment: Is classpath setting to be done by using this:: CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar

Comment: Refer this
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Comment: export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar
this is actually a one liner where you set the CLASSPATH and export it

Comment: May be even this will help you
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/classpath.html

Comment: this has to be done on the terminal ryt??export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar

Comment: try doing sudo yum install libmysql-java
and ya this has to be done in terminal

Comment: No sudheesh dis ain't workin either.Am geting error::                            This is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.

Comment: Download my-sql-conneector from here. Since you are working in fedora go fro tar.gz one
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/3.1.html

extract it and set classpath by changing the path in the above mentioned command
eg:export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:<path of java/mysql-connector-java.jar>

Comment: The classpath environment is almost never used, except for the simplest of application (and not when you for example use an IDE).

Comment: But its not mentioned that he is using any IDE.